# How would you use 化かす?

Tags: word-choice, words, expressions

The dictionary says that it means 'To bewitch.' Could you please give an example of it's use and when you'd use it?

Thank you immensely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an example from 大辞林:

- [狐]{きつね}に[化]{ば}かされる ("bewitched by a fox")

In this case, what did the bewitching (the fox) is followed by に and the appropriate form of [化]{ば}かす.

If you wanted to add who was being bewitched, just add them as a subject, followed by は, at the beginning.  From there it works like any other Japanese verb.